# Magento 2 CSS does not apply

Tags: magento2, css

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Magento 2 on my localhost, i have made a custom theme and now my problem is that i can't change any css ! I have created my css file in **/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/web/css/style.css** and included it in **Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml** like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/style.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

After this I tried this command:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ro_RO
```

I got this in the console:

```
    Running "less:themename" (less) task
File pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/ro_RO/css/styles-m.css created: 284.76
kB → 491.43 kB
File pub/static/frontend/Vendor/themename/ro_RO/css/styles-l.css created: 51.08 k
B → 90 kB

Done, without errors.
```

Still nothing on frontend, i tried this command too:
    grunt less:themename
No changes on frontend. Does anybody have an idea why this is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Checking Ctrl+U CSS add or not.
If already add that CSS apply.
define in layout file module name and deploy again.

```
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_ModuelName::css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code in the below format

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Inside your theme and a custom.css file name in the web/css folder...